# How to resolve Error when Creating new angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

**Background**

I had npm 6.4.1 & node 8.12.0 on my windows machine.
I tried to upgrade In following order

- First upgraded npm
- then node

Now when I try to create a new app … I get error as attached
Very new to angular & node , hoping to get some help here.
[image]
[image]

Comment: did you install angular cli?

Comment: Here are the instructions to install the cli. https://angular.io/cli

Comment: yes i did , still the same issue

Comment: @cgTag when i used "ng new my-first-app" it worked... thanks ... i am undable to accept your comment as answer ... can you post same as answer so that i can accept and close this question

Comment: Thank you, but providing links isn't really a quality answer. I earn my rep points the hard way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without the npm run.
Just with the "ng new my-first-app".

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a little bit of explanation to the future readers of this question, as to why it didn't worked with `npm run ng new my-first-app` but worked with `ng new my-first-app`.

When you write `npm run` it searches for `package.json` in the current directory.
If `package.json` file is present, then it searches for the scripts variable to complete the command. An example of `package.json` is as follows:

### package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
  ...
}
```

So, npm run will not yield anything. But if you run `npm run build`, it will run `ng build --prod` command for you.

If someone still wants to run `npm run ng new my-first-app` command, they can easily do it. By just adding a simple `package.json` file, in the directory under which you want to run these npm commands.

### package.json

```
{  
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng"
   }
}
```

The above `package.json` file will allow you to run all the `ng` commands through `npm` in the current directory.

Comment: thanks appreciate your inputs , helps me understand things better now